# Can someone give a clue with those errors from gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, ffmpeg, libavformat

I have this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    avcodec_register_all();
    av_register_all();

    struct AVCodecTag * const *avctag;
    AVOutputFormat *outputFormat = NULL;

    const char *file = "file.mp4";
    outputFormat = av_guess_format(0, file, 0);

    if( ! outputFormat)
    {
        printf ("No container found\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    printf("%s %d\n",outputFormat->long_name,outputFormat->video_codec);

    avctag = outputFormat->codec_tag[0];
    printf("%d\n",avctag->id);
}
```

The compiler gives this weird error even though I used the -> in the printf line:

```
error: ‘*avctag’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
  printf("%d\n",avctag->id);
```

But it gives also a warning:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  avctag = outputFormat->codec_tag;
```

AVOutputFormat:codec_tag is defined according to the docs as:

struct AVCodecTag * const *

That is exactly as I defined the pointer above. Can someone give me a clue why I get the warning and the error?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `avctag` declared ,like a pointer to a constant pointer

```
struct AVCodecTag * const *avctag;
```

So this statement

```
printf("%d\n",avctag->id);
```

is invalid.

And you need to check the type of the right hand expression in this statement

```
avctag = outputFormat->codec_tag[0];
```

What is the type of `outputFormat->codec_tag[0]`?

Comment: Even deleting the word "const" I get the same warning and the same error message... but thanks for replying anyway.

Comment: @GiuTor Deleting the qualifier const does not make this double pointer a single pointer. It seems you do not understand what you are doing in the program. You need to investigate the documentation.

Comment: That is what I did, in the documentation the field codec_tag in the AVOutputFormat struct is declared as struct AVCodecTag * const *

Comment: @GiuTor You are using avctag = outputFormat->codec_tag[0]; But the warning is about the statement avctag = outputFormat->codec_tag; How to understand this? What are you doing in this statement?

Comment: I want to get all the codecs id linked to a given container. I gave the source code I'm using. Did you compile it...?

Comment: @GiuTor I did not compile it because I do not know this library. But the messages of the compiler are very clear. What you need is to check types of the used expressions. And the compiler reports in its messages what types for example are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You've got too many `*` in your declaration.

`outputFormat->codec_tag` is `struct AVCodecTag * const *` which means that `outputFormat->codec_tag[0]` is just `struct AVCodecTag const *`

or alternative you could do

```
avctag = outputFormat->codec_tag;
printf("%d\n",avctag[0]->id);
```

Comment: Ok, deleteing one * gets one error only, even worse for me: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘const struct AVCodecTag’ in the printf line

Comment: That would suggest that you're not including the right headers that define what `struct AVCodecTag` is...or maybe it is the other `*` that needs to be removed

Comment: I did. I included libavformat.h. The AVCodecTag is defined at line 521 here https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/avformat.h

Comment: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct AVCodecTag’
  printf("%d\n",avctag[0]->id);
                      ^
enum_codec.c:57:22: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct AVCodecTag’

Comment: Line 521 doesn't define the `struct` - it declares a variable called `codec_tag`. I checked - it definitely isn't defined in that file at all - you'll need to read the docs/headers and find the right one